# Create a JSON-formatted text file with my username and password?

Tags: php, json, api, http, authentication

I'm trying to use PHP to authenticate to a web service by posting to an authentication method with a .txt file containing my username and password formatted in JSON.

It's not working and I'm having a hard time figuring out why not.

Here's the code I'm trying to use.  First there's a function I'm using to do the posting.  Then I create a variable for my data file and another for my URL for the AUTH service.

```
<?php 


function do_post_request($url, $data, $optional_headers = null)
{
  $params = array('http' => array(
           'method' => 'POST',
          'content' => $data
        ));
  if ($optional_headers !== null) {
$params['http']['header'] = $optional_headers;
  }
  $ctx = stream_context_create($params);
  $fp = @fopen($url, 'rb', false, $ctx);
   if (!$fp) {
throw new Exception("Problem with $url, $php_errormsg");
  }
  $response = @stream_get_contents($fp);
  if ($response === false) {
throw new Exception("Problem reading data from $url, $php_errormsg");
  }
  return $response;
}

// Let's get logged in and get an authkey 

$url = 'http://service.com/auth';
$data= 'creds.txt';

$authkey = do_post_request($url, $data);  
      
        print_r($authkey);  

 ?>
```

The text of my creds.txt file:

```
{
  "auth": {
      "username": "myusername",
      "password": "mypassword"
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?  I'm getting an invalid data error.  Do I need to use a full URL to the text file?  Is the textfile not formatted properly?

The docs for the service only say that I need:

> "a JSON-formatted text file with your username and password"

Comment: on which line do you get the error? Furthermore it might be that the text file contents is read as a string and is not parsed as json...

Comment: Maybe the service excepts the `application/json` header?

Comment: The error I get says "error":"Username or password not set in request","error_description":"the username\/password value is not valid","error_code":"INVALID_LOGIN"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without disclosing "`service.com`" or more details about the website itself it'll be hard to figure out a solution since it can be a number of things but you're never passing the actual data (only the file path).

Try:

```
$authkey = do_post_request($url, file_get_contents($data));
```

Comment: Problem solved!  Was missing some spaced in the jSON file. :(  No idea JSON was so picky about char spacing

Answer (score 1):

`$data= 'creds.txt';` should be like:

```
$data= file_get_contents('creds.txt');
```

I don't see you open the `creds.txt` anywhere, I believe you should send in jSON format.